# Скрипт, меняющий свойства объекта не работает в IE (не в IE нет проблем)

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Доброго всем времени суток, господа

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><!--JQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.core.full.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script>
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1041';}, 0500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1042';}, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1043';}, 2500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1044';}, 3500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1045';}, 4500);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">

<table class="my_1040" id="hr40">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Собственно скрипт - меняет свойство дива как написано. 0,5с, 1,5с... работает в любом браузере кроме IE. Допустим был фон красный, станет синий... да вообще все что угодно. Подскажите, как реализовать его работу в IE ?

Comment: Может быть, loadPage не объявлена и из-за нее все проблемы?

Comment: эммм.. в боди же прописал. или нужно еще где то? O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> эммм.. в боди же прописал. или нужно еще где то? O_o

дык а функция-то где?? :) в боди ты прописал имя функции, которую надо запустить при загрузке страницы, но **САМУ** функцию ни где не задал.

Comment: допустим это так. подскажите как написать функцию? в боди перенести все? сейчас попробую... спустя минуту: спасибо за чертовски правильное замечание. все сработало.

Comment: а что она должна делать? может и не надо ее.

вообще в ИЕ у меня тоже были проблемы с JS, если перенести в конец страницы прямо перед </body> то может и заработать, а вообще раз исползуется jquery, то лучше его и использовать.
воопервых все функции обернуть в 
<script>
$(function() { 
// тут буду все javascript функции
});

 да и вообще :)

setTimeout(function(){ $('#hr40').addClass('my_1041'); }, 0500);

Раз подключили jquery -- используйте jquery

Comment: смысл обертки в том, что все строки внутри обертки будут запущены как только страница загрузится доконца!

Answer (score 2):

А если так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="Stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script><!--JQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.core.full.js"></script><!--JQEQ-->
<script>
function loadPage(){
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1041';}, 0500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1042';}, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1043';}, 2500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1044';}, 3500);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('hr40').className += ' my_1045';}, 4500);
}
window.onload = loadPage; 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table class="my_1040" id="hr40">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

?

Comment: вообще класс! акцепт правда уже влепил, а 2 нельзя

Comment: Но можно первый отменить (нажав на него если не позно):)

Comment: моя идея красивееее)